# entry value of a map depends on environment variable in spring

Tags: java, spring

I have a spring map declare in the application context xml like this:

```
<map>
    <entry key="mykey">
       <value>${${env}.userkey}</value>
    </entry> 
</map>
```

However the value never be substituted by the environment. Is there a way to do this?

Thanks,

Sean

Comment: I don't do Spring, but is that supposed to be EL or something proprietary? If EL, what scope is `${env}` supposed to be in? Request, session or application?

Comment: the env can be either system property or environment variable. In my test i am using system property at java command line: -Denv=local

Comment: Ah well, that'll be something proprietary. Sorry, don't know :) If it were EL and the `${env}` is in the application scope, then `${applicationScope[env].userkey}` should have worked.

Comment: Add information, witch Spring version you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does #{systemProperties} support environment variables? What's about using PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer which does ([link](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.html#setSearchSystemEnvironment%28boolean%29))

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd
">

<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="location" value="classpath:env.properties" />
</bean>

<util:map id="map">
    <entry key="mykey">
       <value>${${env}.userkey}</value>
    </entry>
</util:map>
```

env.properties:

```
local.userkey=Me
```

Unit test:

```
package org.test;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.annotation.Resource;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;

@ContextConfiguration
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class EnvTest {

    @Resource
    private Map<String, String> map;

    @Test
    public void testMap() throws Exception {
        assertEquals("Me", map.get("mykey"));
    }

}
```

Comment: `systemProperties` don't, but `systemEnvironment` does ;] Property placeholder is good way to go, but, you provided only the way to read properties from custom file, no environment or cmd args.

Comment: according to [systemPropertiesMode](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.6/api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.html#setSystemPropertiesMode%28int%29) and [searchSystemEnvironment](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.6/api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.html#setSearchSystemEnvironment%28boolean%29) properties property placeholder searches environment and system properties too.

Comment: My problem is that somehow it doesn't work with my spring-servlet.xml which has oauth namespace in it. When I move it into another xml, it works.

Answer (score 2):

**If you are using Spring 3**

In Spring configs you can use [SpEL](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/spring-framework-reference/html/ch07.html), and what you need is probably [systemProperties](http://gordondickens.com/wordpress/2011/05/12/spring-expression-language-spel-predefined-variables/) like this:

```
<map>
    <entry key="mkey" value="#{ systemProperties['env'] + '.userkey' }" />
</map>
```

Comment: Shouldn't that `'env'` be unquoted as that's a variable as well?

Comment: No, it's not var - its key and `systemProperties` is a map.

Comment: It doesn't work. It doesn't do the second replacement of 'local.userkey' when 'env=local'.

Comment: Maybe you can try #{#{...}} ?